# How do I make the Firebase Java Event API return events like the SSE API?

Tags: java, firebase, server-sent-events, firebase-realtime-database

When I was first prototyping with Firebase, I used Python with a SSEClient API to stream update events. And it worked as I expected; If I subscribed to the entire document and if I updated just /v_42/lastUpdate therein, I would get an SSE event such as:

```
{ "event": "put", 
  "data" :{"path":"/v_42/lastUpdate","data":{"timestamp":9052758}}}
```

Is there a way to get a specific path of an update using the Java API? The closest thing I can find is

```
firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) { ... }
```

... but the snapshot.getKey() only returns the top level key (i.e., "v_42", not the entire path of the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a different API, so it exposes things differently. But the same information is going to be there.

For example, to get the path of the data in a snapshot:

```
snapshot.getRef().toString().substring(snapshot.getRef().getRoot().toString().length())
```

On the other hand, if you want the information as delivered by the REST API, you can use the REST API from Java too.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But when I try that, I only get back "/v_42" not "/v_42/lastUpdate". 
Is there any way to get the latter back without using the ReST API? How do I detect the actual part of the tree that was changed with the Java API? I would rather not use ReST if I didn't have to due to extra dependencies and overhead.

Comment: That depends on where you attached the listener. Since you're using a child-listener, you might still miss the level of the parent node. But if you're not looking to use the same REST API, you should really invest the time to also change the other logic. There are not many cases where I see developers who need to reconstruct the path. While it is possible to do so, there are often better solutions if you take a few steps back (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: I'm sure this is not the typical use case--I'm using Firebase to hold a collection of document models that will be updated by a mobile UI, but because of the downstream interface, I can only send the changes to the model on an attribute (vice complete document) as a serial command. The UI enforces a single attribute update to FB, to which I was hoping to just get the updated attribute in the document, which could then be re-serialized and transmitted to the downstream system.

Comment: So, given that, let me rephrase X--is there a way to subscribe to the entire database but only receive the path and updated value of a single attribute using the Java API? Otherwise, I would have to maintain all of the "current" document models on my side, deserialize the updated entire model and calculate a diff--which looks error prone when FB seems to do that already using a different API. If not, do you have a recommendation for a Java SSE client API (besides Jetty)?

Comment: No, there is no way to get events on all paths. The Firebase SDK has its own internal model for the data you listen to. It allows you to listen to specific locations and to lists under specific locations. Those are the two use-cases that correspond to most applications: show an item from the data on the screen or show a list of items from the database on the screen. If you're use-case is different, you'll have to do more legwork. Like constructing the path as I've described in my answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanations. I guess I'm off to implement the ReST route then.